# Zend project public name in url

Tags: zend-framework

Hi i've done a zend project that works on localhost correctly. Now i want to put it on a server web...i don't have permission to create a virtual host so all i can use is .htaccess. I have a htaccess on a root like that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And the htaccess on the public folder

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

but when i see the url of the remote page is www.domain.it/public/controlle/action?

How can i remove the public on the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the public folder, put your `.htaccess` and `index.php` file in your `public_html` folder or the equivalent.  The `public` directory in Zend Framework is just a placeholder for whatever your actual public web directory is.

Use the standard Zend Framework `.htaccess` file.  You don't need any fancy rewrite rules.

You can put your ZF application files one level up from your `public_html` folder, or anywhere else.  If you don't put them one level up from public, make sure to change `APPLICATION_PATH` in index.php to reflect the correct location.

Comment: I did what you sed but i had an error on that line: require_once 'Zend/Application.php'  Do you know why?

Comment: Also, if you keep your ZF folder - containing `application`, `library`, `scripts`, `data`, etc - inside your web root, be sure to add an `.htaccess` file with `Deny From All`. Don't want someone browsing to `http://example.com/application/configs/application.ini` and getting at the private goodies.